# I want to block electron app from communicating with outside world

Tags: electron, firewall

I've developed an electron application and packaged it for windows x32. It's a standalone desktop app, and I want to make sure it doesn't communicate with the outside world. When I launch the compiled application for the first time, I get a prompt message asking me if I'd like to "Allow incoming network connections"

If i say no, I believe the app doesn't run properly as it will be added to my firewall's blacklist. Any advice on what the proper practices for achieving this are?

I want to block any incoming/outgoing traffic to/from my electron app, while ensuring tit runs smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

by allowing incoming connection ,you may get trouble .as you have the Proper firewall to prevent it and you proceed